# Entity Framework Core decimal value rounding

Tags: entity-framework-core

We have migrated to Entity Framework Core version 8.0.0. Previously, we used Entity Framework version 6.4.0. We have a decimal column in one of our database tables having precision/scale as (18,2).
Since migrating to Entity Framework Core, we observed that the value after the decimal point is rounded differently. For example,

- With Entity Framework, value 1021.667 would be stored as 1021.66 in the respective column.
- With Entity Framework Core, value 1021.667 is stored as 1021.67.

We don't want the rounding to be changed as the values in column are critical for certain calculations. Please suggest.

Tried specifying the column precision & scale on the respective property in the entity model in code, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's caused by a breaking change (welcome to open source world) in [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient) package which EF Core SqlServer provider is using internally. Actually it is presented as a feature, with backward incompatible default behavior, and opt-out switch to get the old behavior.

Reference: [Enabling decimal truncation behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/appcontext-switches?view=sql-server-ver16#enabling-decimal-truncation-behavior):

> Starting with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 2.0, decimal data is rounded by default, as is done by SQL Server. To enable the previous behavior of truncation, you can set the AppContext switch "Switch.Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TruncateScaledDecimal" to true at application startup:
>
> ```cs
> AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TruncateScaledDecimal", true);
> ```

So you can use the aforementioned "official" workaround.

I personally won't rely on external library behaviors if have a decimal value which is critical to be rounded in a certain way, and simply will do explicitly the desired rounding myself. For instance, truncating to 2 decimals as in your example:

```cs
public class MyEntity
{
    private decimal _myValue;
    public decimal MyValue
    {
        get => _myValue;
        set => _myValue = decimal.Round(value, 2, MidpointRounding.ToZero);
    }
}
```

For EF Core specifically you can also keep the auto property in the model

```cs
public class MyEntity
{
    public decimal MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

and utilize EF Core [value converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations):

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(e => e.Value)
    .HasPrecision(18, 2)
    .HasConversion(
        v => decimal.Round(v, 2, MidpointRounding.ToZero),
        v => v);
```

but still I (again personally) prefer the explicit property setter approach since it's the only one where what you see is what you get (is stored).

Comment: Thanks Ivan, will try this and revert.